# Рекурсивный подсчёт файлов в каталоге

Tags: java, рекурсия

Здравствуйте! Есть задача: Написать программу подсчитывающую количество файлов(файлов и каталогов) в  данном каталоге и во всех содержащихся подкаталогах при помощи рекурсии. Имеется следующий поток сознания:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Testament 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        FileFly file = new FileFly();

        System.out.println(file.fileFly("c:/chocho/"));

    }

}

class FileFly
{

    private File   file;
    private File[] s ;
    private int    c    = 0;

    public int fileFly(String path)
    {   
         file = new File(path);   
         s    = file.listFiles();
         for(int j=0;j<s.length;j++)
         {
             c++;
             if(s[j].isDirectory())
                 fileFly(s[j].getPath());
         }
         return c;

    }

}
```

Вот то, на чём остановился. Помогите добрым советом. Как допилить данный код, что бы работал как надо? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы почти сами доделали работу, вот только поля класса должны быть членами метода.

```
class FileFly {

private int c = 0;

public int fileFly(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    File[] s = file.listFiles();
    for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
        if(!s[j].isDirectory())
        c++;
        if (s[j].isDirectory())
            recursionSearc(s[j].getPath());
    }
    return c;
}
```

}

Comment: Немного видоизменил ваш вариант кода и всё заработало.Благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Вот кусок моего старого кода, он не совсем для подсчета файлов и каталогов, а для распечатки дерева данного каталога! Но думаю переделать для вашего случая совсем не сложно:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class File_Directory {
        //main procedure
        public static void main (String[] arg){
                Scanner scanner=new Scanner (System.in);

                System.out.println("Enter directory: ");
                String Path=scanner.nextLine();
                printTreeFiles(Path);
        }

        public static void printTreeFiles(String Path){
                File Directory = new File (Path);

                if (Directory.exists()){
                        getContent(Directory,0);
                }
                else System.out.println("Directory is not found...");
                }
        //recursive procedure for finding the contents of a directory
        public static void getContent(File Directory,int Indents)
        {
                for (int i=0;i<Indents;i++) System.out.print("\t");

                if (Directory.isFile()) System.out.println(Directory.getName());
                else {
                        System.out.println(Directory.getName());
                        File[] SubDirectory = Directory.listFiles();
                        for (File SubWay:SubDirectory)
                                getContent(SubWay,Indents+1);
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Изучил ваш код, кое что подчерпнул для себя.

Answer (score 1):

Надо написать метод, который проверяет содержимое папки и вызывал бы сам себя, если в содержимом находилась еще одна папка и так до бесконечности. Например такой:

```
public void searchFile(File dir) throws IOException {
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory())
                    searchFile(file);  
            }
            for (File file : files) {
                int n=0;
                if (file.isFile()) {   //проверяем, файл ли это
                    n++;
                    System.out.println("Файл номер "+n+" найден в " + file.getAbsolutePath());
```