# Обойти все поддиректории и переименовать файлы внутри в зависимости от типа файла

Tags: java

Доброго дня всем.
Пытаюсь написать программу, которая должна обойти все подкаталоги в папке и изменить содержимое в подкаталоге.
Суть: есть папка, в ней несколько сотен/тысяч других папок, а в каждой из них уже несколько файлов.
Необходимо их все обойти, зайти в каждую, и в зависимости от расширения переименовать по шаблону: 
заходим в 1-ую папку - видим блбла.json -переименовываем в 1.json,то же самое с текстовыми, и т.д.

Код:

```
import java.io.File;

public class Sorter{
    //main procedure
    public static void main(String[] arg) {

        String Path = Utils.pathFileData;
        printTreeFiles(Path);
    }

    public static void printTreeFiles(String Path) {
        File Directory = new File(Path);//ccыль на главную папку, внутри которой 1000 папок
        File[] SubDirectory = Directory.listFiles();
            getContent(SubDirectory);
            System.out.println();
    }

    //recursive procedure for finding the contents of a directory
    public static void getContent(File[] SubDirectory) {//трясём папки

        for (int i=0; i< SubDirectory.length; i++) {//
         //   System.out.print("\t");
           // System.out.println(Directory.getName());
            //File[] SubDirectory = Directory.listFiles();
            for (File SubWay:SubDirectory) {//для каждого файла из одной из 1000 папок

               // getContent(SubWay, i + 1);
                String buf = SubWay.getName();  // читаем текущее имя файла
               // System.out.println(buf);
                if (buf.contains("ARTICLE"))// 
                {
                    buf = buf.replace(".txt", "Article" + i + ".txt");
                    SubWay.renameTo(new File(Utils.pathFileData + buf));
                } else if (buf.endsWith(".json")) {
                    buf = buf.replaceFirst(".json", i + ".json");
                    SubWay.renameTo(new File(Utils.pathFileData + buf));
                } else
                    buf = buf.replaceFirst(".txt", i + ".txt");
                SubWay.renameTo(new File(Utils.pathFileData + buf));

            }


        }

    }

}
```

Код вместо этого делает следующее: присоединяет название файла с расширением .txt к папке, в которой находится этот файл.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, что надо поменять, чтобы запахало не косо.

Похожие треды здесь уже прочитаны, как болванку взял код вот отсюда: 
[Рекурсивный подсчёт файлов в каталоге](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/63961/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5)

Comment: `Utils.pathFileData + buf` -> `Utils.pathFileData + "/" + buf`?

Comment: @kff, попробовал-никакой разницы, вроде.
Самое главное, что файлы внутри папки по-прежнему никак не изменяются.

Answer (score 1):

Не ясно, каким образом нумеруются директории. Если нет, определенных правил, то вот это должно быть решением.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {

    AtomicLong directoryNumber = new AtomicLong(0);
    Path start = Paths.get("/home/artem/");

    Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {

            String fileName = file.getFileName().toString();
            String newFileName;
            int index = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
            if (index == -1)
                newFileName = fileName;
            else
                newFileName = directoryNumber.get() + fileName.substring(index);

            Path target = Paths.get(file.getParent().toString(), newFileName);
            Files.copy(file, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            directoryNumber.incrementAndGet();
            return super.preVisitDirectory(dir, attrs);
        }
    });
}
```